# Javascript, filter object list using string condition?

Tags: javascript, filter, implicit

I have this object structure:

```js
var objList = [
    { "age": 19, "valueField": 34, "booleanField": false },
    { "age": 15, "valueField": 5,  "booleanField": false },
    { "age": 22, "valueField": 17, "booleanField": true }
];
```

And this condition

```js
var condition = 'age > 18 && age < 30 && booleanField == true';
```

I know I can do it using a simple filter function

```js
var newObjList = objList.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.age > 18 && obj.age < 30 && obj.booleanField == true;
});
```

But I want to use the condition "as is", without having to concatenate "obj." before every field. Something like this

```js
objList.filter(function(obj) {
    return conditon; // all the fields referenced in the condition should point to the corresponding obj fields
})
```

This can be seen as a SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM objlist
where " + condition + ";
```

Can this be done?

Comment: I'm hearing you want to define a small domain specific language with parser…?

Comment: Read breeze.js that is client side ORM. In which you can create predicates and apply filter dynamically.

Comment: How are you getting the `condition` string? Can you have something else instead of it?

Comment: The condition string comes from my java backend, I can't change it. Im not allowed to use third party libraries, let alone parsers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Note:**

I'm starting with this note to mention that the solution to the problem uses both `with` and `eval` which should be used with total carefulness (use it only if you **guarantee** that the `condition` string won't contain **malicious code**).

**Solution:**

You can use `eval` and `with` to achieve that like so:

```
var newObjList = objList.filter(function(obj) {
    return eval("with(obj) {" + condition + "}");
});
```

**Example:**

```js
var objList = [ { "age": 19, "valueField": 34, "booleanField": false }, { "age": 15, "valueField": 5,  "booleanField": false }, { "age": 22, "valueField": 17, "booleanField": true } ];
var condition = 'age > 18 && age < 30 && booleanField == true';

var newObjList = objList.filter(function(obj) {
    return eval("with(obj) {" + condition + "}");
});

console.log(newObjList);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could replace all known keys of the object in `condition` with an object suffix and generate a new function as callback with replaced condition and return statement.

Maybe you need to padd the keys for replacements to prevent to replace unwanted substrings.

```js
var array = [{ age: 19, valueField: 34, booleanField: false }, { age: 15, valueField: 5, booleanField: false }, { age: 22, valueField: 17, booleanField: true }];
    condition = 'age > 18 && age < 30 && booleanField == true',
    cb = new Function('o', 'return ' + condition.replace(new RegExp(Object.keys(array[0]).join('|'), 'g'), 'o.$&'));

console.log(array.filter(cb));
```